# How to Select a dropdown list in a javascrip site using selenium in python3?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

I am stuck in the following html code taken from a site that uses Javascript. What I want is to select the item "Short_Budget_Report" in Selenium using Select moduele. The html code is as follows:

```
<input id="WD51" ct="CB" lsdata="{1:'20ex',8:'WD52',9:'2347',11:'Short_Budget_Report',14:'Load\x20View',18:'View',44:false,48:'WD51\x2dtlbl'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Load View" class="lsField__input urEdf2TxtEnbl lsEdfLeftBrdRadius lsEdf3TxtHlpBtn urEdfVAlign urBorderBox lsControl--explicitwidth" readonly="" value="Short_Budget_Report" style="vertical-align:top;width:20ex;">
```

What I have tried:

```
dropdown_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="WD51"]')
    dropdown = Select(dropdown_id)
    dropdown.select_by_value('Short_Budget_Report')
```

This gives the following error:

```
raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>
```

Comment: there is some error related to your xpath. may be you have selected xpath of wrong element . please share site link so that I can help you

Comment: it appears that you work on input tag rather than dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `send_keys()` function to select particular option in dropdown list.

1. First locate the element of dropdown list by any of `find_element()` function
2. use `send_keys()` function on that element to select any value from list right away

In short, doing it in following way should get done what you need:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('WD51').send_keys('Short_Budget_Report')
```